# Distance between a point and subspace of even functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

Let $T:L^2[-1, 1]\to L^2[-1, 1]$ be defined by $$Tf=f_1,$$ where $$f_1(x)=f(-x)$$ almost everywhere.
Let $M$ be the kernel of $$I-T,$$ where $I$ is the identity map. Then find the distance between $e^t$ and $M$.

My Attempt: I know that the distance between a point and a subspace is the distance between the point and its orthogonal projection onto that subspace. Here $M$ is the set of all the functions of $L^2[-1, 1]$ that are even almost everywhere. In order to find the orthogonal projection, I need the basis of $M$ but I am not able to derive its basis. Am I thinking it on the right way or Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I will asssume that you are using real $L^{2}$].

Instead of finding  a basis for $M$ you could identify the orthogonal complement. Let us show that $M^{\perp}$ is the collection of all odd functions.
If $f$ is even and $g$ is odd then $f(x)g(x)$ is odd so $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx=0$.  Coversely. if $g$ is orthogonal to every even function then $\int [g(t)+g(-t)]f(t)dt=\int f(t)g(t)dt+\int f(t)g(-t)dt=\int f(t)g(t)dt-\int f(-t)g(t)dt=0$ for every $f$ so $g(t)+g(-t)=0$ almost everywhere.

This proves that $M^{\perp}$ is the collection of all odd functions.

Now $L^{2}=M\oplus M^{\perp}$ and the unique decomposition of any elemenet $f$ as a sum of an element of $M$ and an element of $M^{\perp}$ is exactly $f(x)=\frac {f(x)+f(-x)} 2 +\frac {f(x)-f(-x)} 2$. Hence, the projection on $M$ is given by $P_M f(x)=\frac {f(x)+f(-x)} 2$.